# Does EC2 Elastic Load Balancer remove the need for apache/nginx?

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I am striving for a very simple cloud based architecture on Amazon AWS. I would like to have an app layer of several "elastic" EC2 instances where my application (and application servers) run, but I'm wondering what the load balancing will look like.

If I choose to use ELB, does it remove the need for Apache or Nginx?

Comment: I'm not a fan of the drive-by downvotes either--I like knowing why there is an issue. Despite AWS becoming  a fairly ubiquitous development tool, some folks are hardcore about keeping anything server or system related on ServerFault or other sites if no code is involved at all.  I'm guessing this might be the issue.  
I've always thought the system of segregating development/administration/etc topics to seperate sites to be a bit overdone and counter-productive, but I've learned the rational of the supporters of it--they're valid even if I disagree.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, Ray. The lines are certainly a little blurry there, but at least now I have a good idea of why folks may have taken issue. Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  All the loadbalancer does is just that, distributes load across instances.   Whatever your stack is running on each instance will still need a nginx or apache or whatever service you want to respond back to the request routed through the load balancer.

I'm assuming you're running a web stack needing some type of server like nginx, apache, or java needing tomcat or something.

However, if you want AWS to take care of nginx and/or apache, look into running as a ElasticBeanstalk application: https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/

Comment: Thanks for your response. Correct, tomcat is necessary on the "app layer." Wouldn't it be bad practice though to have nginx running on each app layer instance? It seems, given what you've told me, that perhaps I should use nginx (instead of ELB) as that top layer so that it could process the request AND act as the load balancer, taking one level of complexity out of the equation?

Comment: @BrianFitzGerald no, if you're wanting to distribute load across multiple ec2 instances use an ELB.

Comment: @BrianFitzGerald  Treat each instance behind the load balancer as their own stack.  If you don't need the location base routing, proxying, and rewriting of nginx/apache (you're only running tomcat an nothing else), you can leave it out.

Comment: @BrianFitzGerald Honestly, I'd look at elastic beanstock for a tomcat application.   EB handles provisioning and management of the instances, ELBs, and everything.  You just provide the java code.